# org-mode html export

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have a org file with source, documentation and latex code. Latex stuff draws a bunch of graphs explaining how functions interact with each other. According to,

http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html

org-mode should export latex code as images when using html export.

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Blah
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+OPTIONS: LaTeX:dvipng

#+begin_latex

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}

#+end_latex
```

Above works if I use pdf export so my latex setup is working also dvipng is present on my system but when exporting to html latex block is completely ignored.

Comment: I wonder what do you expect from html exporter.

Comment: @kindahero, I certainly don't expect it to make me a cup of coffee but I do expect it to render the graph with dvipng and embed it into the html.

Comment: Then i guess you should use babel http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to make tikzpicture blocks working but `#+begin_latex` and `#+end_latex` shouldn't be use, as said in your link to the Org-Mode documentation, only `\begin{...} LATEX_CODE end{...}` is required.

This snippet should work.

```
#+OPTIONS:      LaTeX:dvipng
* Test
  Blah

  \begin{equation}                          % arbitrary environments,
  x=\sqrt{b}                                % even tables, figures
  \end{equation}                            % etc

  If $a^2=b$ and \( b=2 \), then the solution must be either $$
  a=+\sqrt{2} $$ or \[ a=-\sqrt{2} \].

  Done !
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to export a tikz picture from org to html (actually, to
reveal.js using [org-reveal][1] ) from org 8.2.5h with the following

```
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

* Slide Title

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [blue,fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,3);
    \draw [red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I hope that's helpful. Without the `#+LaTeX_Header` line, the LaTeX
process doesn't know to include tikz, and the build fails. If I try
`tex:dvipng` instead of `tex:imagemagick`, then I get an image, but an
incorrectly rendered one.

Comment: that's exactly what I have been looking for the whole day (also to get it to work in org-reveal btw)!

Answer (score 7):

With recent versions of Org-mode (yet, older than version 9 --- see edit below), you could use something like the following, that can export to LaTeX as well as to HTML. In the latter case, `convert` (from the ImageMagick toolkit) is used to translate a PDF generated from the tikz code snippet into a PNG image of size 100px by 100px.

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Blah
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [american]
#
# Setup tikz package for both LaTeX and HTML export:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :packages '(("" "tikz"))
#
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :imagemagick (by-backend (latex nil) (t "yes"))
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :exports results :fit yes

* One Diamond

#+name: diamond
#+header: :iminoptions -density 600 -resample 100x100
#+header: :file (by-backend (latex "diamond.tikz") (t "diamond.png"))
#+begin_src latex :results raw file
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src

#+attr_latex: :float nil :width ""
#+results: diamond

* COMMENT setup

#+name: setup
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports none
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
#+end_src

# Local variables:
# eval: (org-sbe "setup")
# End:
```

Besides, one can add a caption, and insert the picture in a floating `figure` environment in LaTeX, by using:

```
#+caption: A diamond.
#+attr_latex: :float t :width ""
#+results: diamond
```

Note the `:width` attribute is set to the empty string to erase the default behavior of Org-mode, which sets the width of the picture to `0.9\textwidth` when exporting to LaTeX.

---

According to [this page](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html), it is also possible to export pictures in SVG instead of PNG, simply by replacing `diamond.png` by `diamond.svg` and removing ImageMagick-related headers, as in:

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Blah
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [american]
#
# Setup tikz package for both LaTeX and HTML export:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :packages '(("" "tikz"))
#
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :exports results

* One Diamond

#+name: diamond
#+header: :file (by-backend (latex "diamond.tikz") (t "diamond.svg"))
#+begin_src latex :results raw file
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
    % \node at (0,0) {\(x_i\)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src

#+caption: A diamond.
#+attr_latex: :float t :width ""
#+results: diamond

* COMMENT setup

#+name: setup
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports none
  ;; (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
#+end_src

# Local variables:
# eval: (org-sbe "setup")
# End:
```

Note however that this solution does not support mathematical macros in tikz code as is. [`htlatex`](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) ought to support basic mathematical constructs (to be tried by un-commenting the 2 tikz and lisp lines above), but this feature needs some rework apparently, as the resulting SVG is invalid.

---

**Edit**

Since version 9, the code above becomes (with a reference to the figure, for illustrative purposes):

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Blah
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [american]
#
# Setup tikz package for both LaTeX and HTML export:
#
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :packages '(("" "tikz"))
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :imagemagick yes :fit yes

* One Diamond

#+name: diamond
#+header: :iminoptions -density 600 -resample 100x100
#+header: :file (by-backend (latex "diamond.tikz") (t "diamond.png"))
#+begin_src latex :results raw graphics
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src

#+name: fig:diamond
#+caption: A diamond.
#+attr_latex: :float t :width ""
#+results: diamond

Figure [[fig:diamond]] is a diamond.

* Setup                                                            :noexport:
#+name: setup
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports none :results silent
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case org-export-current-backend ,@body))
#+end_src

# Local variables:
# eval: (org-sbe "setup")
# End:
```

The main differences are in the "COMMENT" becoming a ":noexport" tag for the setup section (see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29821/8242)), the code of `by-backend` macro, and the "graphics" attribute for the result of the latex code block.

Comment: Hello, could you tell what is `latex+` exaclty?

Comment: `#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ <args>` appends `<args>` to the header arguments named `header-args:latex`. This is somehow "guessable" [in the docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html#Property-syntax) (though I agree this could be improved).

Answer (score 3):

dvipng does not handle tikz.  I've worked around this on my installation by replacing dvipng with the following shell script:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 shift
 shift
 dvips $9
 gm convert -trim $9 ${9/dvi/png}
```

Now, I can preview a tikz snippet with C-x C-c C-l, or export it to HTML. Not an ideal solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Any luck with this, or are you still using the same workaround? I can't make this work.